# addwatermarkfromtext() inacrobat not looping

Tags: javascript, acrobat

ok, so I took bits of codes from the internet and managed to get some stuff to work but it only works on the first page and I would like that to be done on every page. I'm sure it's a noob mistake but just haven't found the answer.

The idea is that it writes the filename with a barcode font and the line after the page number, I put it in two different loops to have two different fonts (hoping that it makes sense).

```
    for (var p = 0; p < this.pageNum; p++);
var cMyText = event.target.documentFileName.replace(/\.pdf$/i,"");
event.target.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:10,
    aColor: color.black,
    cFont: "LibreBarcode39Text-Regular",
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
    nHorizValue: 36,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
    nVertValue: -3,
    nStart: p
})
for (var s=0; s<this.pageNum; s++);
var cMyText = "\nPage " + (s+1) + " of " + numPages;
event.target.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nFontSize:8,
    aColor: color.black,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
    nHorizValue: 36,
    nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
    nVertValue: -10,
    nStart: s

})
```

edit: I wasn't understanding brackets as explained by Christopher...

final code that works (not in the snipet, it was just the cleanest way to have it..)

```js
/*print identifier script by Chris B. Castonguay 2022*/


/*open a dialog box requesting the workorder number and stores that value*/
var cRtn = app.response("Workorder number (format as: x1-23456-x)","Barcode Creator 2000","roll-up-33","","workorder #");

/*prints the word workorder number in the top left corner*/
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++){
var cMyText = "workorder # ";
event.target.addWatermarkFromText({
        cText: cMyText,
        nFontSize:10,
        aColor: ["CMYK", 0,0,0,.85],
        nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
        nHorizValue: 36,
        nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
        nVertValue: 0,
        nStart: p
})
}
/*generates and print the barcode from the value stored with the dialog box*/
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++){
var cMyText = "*" + cRtn + "*";
event.target.addWatermarkFromText({
        cText: cMyText,
        nFontSize:30,
        aColor: ["CMYK", 0,0,0,.85],
        cFont: "LibreBarcode39Text-Regular",
        nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
        nHorizValue: 100,
        nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
        nVertValue: 0,
        nStart: p
})
}
/*counts the number of pages and identifies them*/
for (var s = 0; s < this.numPages; s++){
    var cMyText = "\nPage " + (s+1) + " of " + numPages;
        event.target.addWatermarkFromText({
            cText: cMyText,
            nFontSize:8,
            aColor: ["CMYK", 0,0,0,.85],
            nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
            nHorizValue: 36,
            nVertAlign:app.constants.align.top,
            nVertValue: -15,
            nStart: s
    })
```

Comment: `for(;;);` is like `for (;;) { /* do nothing */ }`. Use brackets and put the actions to be done inside the block.

Comment: your comment allowed me to figure it out, clearly I wasn't understanding how to correctly use brackets... here's the final code I ended up with (there's more that I want to do with it but that will be for the next iteration, for now it works well enough)